# JSON response in jQuery Ajax in Spring Mvc

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc

How to get JSON response in jQuery Ajax in Spring Mvc?
this is my ajax code

```
 $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: "fetch",
       dataType: 'json',
       data:  {clientidedit:clientidedit},
       success: function(data) {

       },
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert("error");
       }

  });
```

here is my service. this will return a string.How can i get each data in ajax response?

```
if (StringUtils.isEmpty(clientId)) {
        resObj.put("clientId", org.json.JSONObject.NULL);
    } else {
        resObj.put("clientId", clientId);
    }

    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(clientName)) {
        resObj.put("clientName", org.json.JSONObject.NULL);
    } else {
        resObj.put("clientName", clientName);
    }
    array.put(resObj);
}

try {
    resObjForTable.put("aaData", array);
} catch (JSONException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(SabbServiceImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
return resObjForTable.toString();
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: What is the return type of your service?

Answer (score 1):

Your controller class method should be like this

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "fetch")
    @ResponseBody
    public Object methodName() {

        // Your implementation.

        return resObjForTable.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your C# code should like this that return "Json"
Try this

```
function JsonResult FunctionName (Param){
if (StringUtils.isEmpty(clientId)) {
        resObj.put("clientId", org.json.JSONObject.NULL);
    } else {
        resObj.put("clientId", clientId);
    }

    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(clientName)) {
        resObj.put("clientName", org.json.JSONObject.NULL);
    } else {
        resObj.put("clientName", clientName);
    }
    array.put(resObj);
}

try {
    resObjForTable.put("aaData", array);
} catch (JSONException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(SabbServiceImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
return json(resObjForTable);
}
```